# HP universal print driver on Samsung SCX5935FN

Tags: hp, printer, drivers

Recently we've been faced with a very odd issue; our Samsung SCX5935FN skips the numbers "6" and "8" whenever it is asked to print a document. Everything else within the document is printed correctly, except for those numbers, it is as if those numbers were never on the document to begin with.

A temporary fix I have been using is to send a .txt file with the numbers "6" and "8" to the printer, after doing this, the printer prints correctly for a while, but then the problem returns seemingly randomly.

This printer is on windows server 2003 and is using the HP universal driver 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm... Why not use the Samsung driver?

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/search/supportSearchModelResult.do?menu=SP01&searchWord=SCX5935FN&searchInputBox=SCX5935FN&find_button=

Comment: Thank you, but I am told that using the Samsung driver isn't an option because it is bad...

Is there any other way to handle the problem without switching to the samsung drivers?

Comment: Who's telling you that the Samsung driver is "bad"? Have you tried it? You don't have anything to lose by trying it.

Comment: My boss is telling me this; apparently Samsung drivers were already tried, and the driver has limitations such as being unable to print with 0 margins and "other issues." So using the Samsung drivers is not an option for us because of such limitations.

Comment: Samsung does have a universal print driver for that model, have you tried it? The HP universal print driver is meant for HP printers so you're probably never going to get it to work correctly for a Samsung printer.

Comment: I figured as much, and yes, he had tried the universal printer driver. What confuses me though is why after printing a .txt with "6" and "8" it works for a short while.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung's latest driver actually *does* work with zero margins and prints seemingly all characters correctly.

I guess that this problem was due to the font type of calibri, as it is a clear-type font, some drivers have problems with some charcters under some sizes of calibri.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I agree, best approach is to use the Samsung drivers and get those working. But (like I said in your other thread), usually setting "Send TrueType as Bitmaps" as Enabled will fix font issues with the HP Universal Print Driver